# Calculating big O notation O(n) and O(n^2)

Tags: java, arraylist, time-complexity, big-o

I have a program which grabs data from an ArrayList which takes O(n) time.

But also have a nested for loop which takes O(n^2) time.

Would the program have a time complexity of O(n^2) or O(n^3)?

Comment: Assuming that I got your description right, it's *O(n^3)*. But you should post the algorithm to know it for sure.

Comment: depends on whether the nested loop executes once for each element of the array or not. As @akuzminykh writes, edit the algorithm (or its pseudocode) into the answer to be sure.

Comment: If the loop is done _after_ the "grab", then the answer is O(n^2). If the loop is performed on _every_ lookup in the O(n) "grab", then the answer is O(n^3). The intuition is that O(n) + O(n^2) = O(n^2), while O(n) * O(n^2) = O(n^3).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends how these two parts interact. If they call each other (e.g., for each element in the list (O(n)) you perform a method that does a nested loop over the entire list (O(n<sup>2</sup>)), you multiply them and get an O(n<sup>3</sup>) time complexity.

If they are called in a serial manner - i.e., you go over the list (O(n)) and once you're one perform an O(n<sup>2</sup>) algorithm, or vise-versa, the O(n) part is negligible compared to the O(n<sup>2</sup>) part, and the overall time complexity is O(n<sup>2</sup>).